# Memory usage monitored by Ubuntu

Tags: memory, java, cache

I am running a Java application on a Ubuntu (Kbuntu). 64G memory. The application has to run for a while to process data.

The System Monitor shows that around 10G memory is being used for the application.

However, in the KInfocenter, among 64G memory, only 20G are free, while 31G are used for Disk Cache. Swap is minimal.

So what's Disk Cache? why does it use so much? Is this normal or not?

Comment: See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/, it's normal, it's *good*, it's used to speed up disk accesses, and it's not caused by your application (the OS does this on its own).

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior of UNIX/Linux. OS try to use for cache of filesystems as much as possible from the memory.

When you run application which need more than 20GB (your free memory) then the OS will free some amount of cache memory and will provide it to the application

Comment: You mean 20G is a threshold for this? Sometimes it shows my "free memory" is only 13G while nearly 40G are cache memory. Isn't it my application's issue? I can't imagine what are cached in filesystems that needs over half memory.

Comment: No, I mean the next: you have xGB free, and run app which need x+10GB so those 10GB will be "stolen" from the cache. And the idea is cache will use whatever free memory you have

Comment: If my app uses 40 cache memory, does that mean it uses more than 40G memory? I am trying to understand my application's memory consumption.